# Absolute position of geom_text in a geom_bar (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to insert some text into a barplot. I manage to, but the positioning is weird, as if it did not start from an equal absolute y-value.

```
data(iris)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = Sepal.Length, fill = "pink"), stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(y=1, label = Species, hjust = -2, angle = 90))
```

[image]

I would like the texts to start all from the same y-value.

Comment: I think the `hjust` is the culprit here. You could remove it and set y to 100.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for my data

Answer (score 3):

Besides the `hjust` problem, you have two other problems with your code: (1) you have to place `fill = "pink"` outside of the `aes` and (2) the `geom_text` plots all the text labels for each group on top of each other which might cause the labels to be not so sharp.

You can fix this as follows:

```
# create a separate labals dataframe
iris.lbl <- data.frame(lbl = levels(iris$Species), y=100)

# make the plot with everything set correctly
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = Sepal.Length), stat = "identity", fill = "pink") +
  geom_text(data = iris.lbl, aes(x=lbl, y=y, label = lbl, hjust=0, angle = 90))
```

which gives:

[image]